# Excel, apply sum to certain cells over multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel, apply sum  to certain cells over multiple columns

```
   A, B, C , D
A, 1, 2, 3 , 4
B, 1, 2, 3 , 4
C, 1, 2, 3 , 4
D, =sum(A1,A2,A3)
so A4=3,
```

How can we apply the sum to the 4 ofB, C,D over B,C D columns respectively?

Comment: Why can't you just use SUM? What is the desired outcome here?

Comment: I am using the SUM.
desired outcome: for row D,  sum over (B1 to B3) to B4,sum over (C1 to C3) to C4, sum over (D1 to D3) to D4

Comment: Then what is the problem? I really don't get it. Just use the formula you have in your sample

Comment: now, doing it one columns at a time, there are more than 200 columns need the same functions. wonder if we could apply the SUM over the columns ( B-D) once, since they are kind of the same.

Comment: So, you need the total of all columns combined?

Comment: no, they need to be individual column. D row, sum up all column individually from respect column from 1-3  Maybe we can't do that in excel, I am thinking using python. or other tool.

Comment: You could try key combos. Place cursor in cell D4. `CTRL` + `Space Bar` to select entire row . `ALT` + `=` to auto sum column D. `CTRL` + `ENTER` to apply result to all selected cells. Note that auto sum works on cells with values so your starting formula cell needs all its cells populated.

Comment: @bugdrown do you similar solution for macOS?

Comment: Apologies, I assumed Windows. I only found mac os keystrokes to select the entire row, here: https://exceljet.net/excel-shortcuts-on-the-mac. Correction to my 1st comment on Windows, its `SHIFT`  + `SPACE BAR` for row selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need dynamic arrays to have a single formula spilling all results. So, if you have access to `BYCOL()`, use:

[image]

Formula in `A4`:

```
=BYCOL(A1:D3,LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))
```

Or, else:

```
=TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(A1:D3),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:D3),,,0)))
```